# Is there a way to include the instance of a service in the Get-Service and Get-WmiObject commands?

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I am trying to write a script that stops a service if it exists. The service I want to stop has multiple instances and I was trying to get the service based on the given instance name (it shows up as `ServiceName$InstanceName`).

The weird thing is when I run the following command:

```
Get-Service -Name "ServiceName*" | Format-List -Property Name
```

or

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "name like 'ServiceName%'" | Format-List -Property Name
```

The results look like:

```
Name : ServiceName$InstanceNameA

Name : ServiceName$InstanceNameB

Name : ServiceName$InstanceNameC

Name : ServiceName$InstanceNameD

Name : ServiceName$InstanceNameE

Name : ServiceName$InstanceNameF
```

Given the above results, I assumed that if I wanted to search for a service named `ServiceName` with an instance of `InstanceNameC` I could do something like

```
Get-Service -Name "ServiceName$InstanceNameC"
```

or

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "name='ServiceName$InstanceNameC'"
```

but it's not working as I would expect.

I guess the long winded question is: Can I find/get a specific service instance by passing it the proper service name of `ServiceName$InstanceName`?

Comment: What is the name of the service you're trying to retrieve?  You can use `Get-Service | Get-Member` to see the properties you can filter off of using `Where-Object`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 See my answer. I found this answer after posting my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1615145/1165441

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Script not accepting $ (Dollar) sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615117/powershell-script-not-accepting-dollar-sign)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Hoping we can find a better dupe. That one does not really explain what is happening nor give the other easy solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm clearly not experienced with powershell, but just found that adding the backtick (`) to escape the dollar sign that separates the service name from the instance name allows the Get-Service to work as I expected.

Here's what worked:

```
Get-Service -Name "ServiceName`$InstanceNameC"
```

Comment: `$` is for variables. They will expand inside double quotes. It was trying to find a service name called "ServiceName" since you have no variable called `$instancename`. This would have worked as well: `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter 'name="ServiceName$InstanceNameC"'`

Comment: That worked and it looks like the reason mine didn't (the one that looks very similar) is because I had the double quotes outside of the single quotes.