# how do I rename files in Powershell with regex?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have some files with word characters and numbers at the end of filename. For some reason my regex is not working. Here are examples of my filenames:

```
test abc12345.zip
abcd def98765.zip
test xyz23456.zip
```

Here is my regex:

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace "(\w\w\w\d\d\d\d\d.zip)","[$1].zip"}
```

When I run the selection snippet it removes:

```
abc12345
def98765
xyz23456
```

from the files names and just inserts the brackets:

```
test [].zip
abcd [].zip
test [].zip
```

How do I keep the contents within the brackets? Not sure why my code is removing everything in between the []

```
test [abc12345].zip
abcd [def98765].zip
test [xyz23456].zip
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Script not accepting $ (Dollar) sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615117/powershell-script-not-accepting-dollar-sign)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the double quotes to single quotes. Powershell parses the content of double quotes and replaces your `$1` with the content of the *(non existent/empty)* variable `$1`

---

Also, your regex can be made simpler to by using quantifiers for your word and digit characters so this

```
 (\w\w\w\d\d\d\d\d.zip)
```

can be changed to this shorter version

```
(\w{3}\d{5}.zip)
```

---

Looking at your expected output, there's another problem with your current capturing group that is including the .zip extension. What you actually want instead of capturing everything including the extension

```
(\w{3}\d{5}.zip)
```

is to capture *only* the word/digit part

```
(\w{3}\d{5}).zip
```

Now you can use the capturing group to put brackets around them. Your final regex and replacement might then look like this

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace '(\w{3}\d{5}).zip','[$1].zip'}
```

Comment: I see another mistake i made:
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace "(\w\w\w\d\d\d\d\d).zip",'[$1].zip'}

moved .zip outside of the group
but the code works great. Thanks!