# Print $ symbol in powershell script

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I need to generate some commands with a PowerShell script, but I can't print the `$` symbol.

```
Write-Host "Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $ Mailbox -User $ User -AccessRight FullAccess -Automapping $false"
```

generates:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity MAILBOX -User USER-AccessRight FullAccess -Automapping False
```

Comment: Is this meant to be some sort of Verbose for your sciprt?

Comment: Use single quotes for verbatim output -> `Write-Host 'Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $Mailbox -User $User -AccessRight FullAccess -Automapping $false'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape special characters in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965466/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-powershell)

Comment: [Escaping dollar signs in PowerShell path is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17452401/995714), [PowerShell script not accepting $ (dollar) sign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1615117/995714)

Answer (score 1):

`` Write-Host "`$" `` works.

In general when programming, special characters need escaping to be printed.  Many language use `\` to escape, PowerShell uses `` ` `` (the backtick, to the left of the 1 on your keyboard).

Comment: To the left of the `1` on my keyboard, I have `°` and `§` ...... remember: **not everyone** in the whole world is using an US-English keyboard....... there *are* other languages, locales, and keyboard layouts out there....

Comment: why Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $ Mailbox -User $ User -AccessRight FullAccess -Automapping $false is not recognized as command?